# Repeat works reuses unnamed register. Bug or a feature?

Tags: register, repeated-commands

Suppose I want to get from this `a,b` to this `'a','b'`
Yeah, yeah, yeah, I know about surround plugin. The cursor is on the start of line
I'm doing `cw<bsp>'<C-r>"`. I have delimitMate plugin, so this would end in `'a',b`.
Now all I need is to repeat the same action on b. But if I'll do that I'll end up with `'a','a'`.
Can't find anything on this in docs. Is this a bug?

Comment: No, you'll insert exactly the same thing, and not the new content of the unnamed register. You'll have to use a macro or a surrounding plugin that'll ease the task.

Comment: @LucHermitte I see that I'm inserting the same stuff, so your comment isn't helpful. What is the logic behind this? Where is this behaviour documented?

Comment: The logic is that the ~redo register is filled not with a reference to the unnamed register, but with its actual content. I doubt it's documented anywhere. The filling of thing breaks easily. `i_CTRL-R` doesn't break it, but fills it with the content it inserts. Alas, this is a readonly thing. As with the dot register, we can't fill it with what we would like.

Comment: @LucHermitte what does `.` register have to do with this? If repeat command repeats the last change why should it mess with unnamed register, just do exactly what I just did

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I've edited my previous comment. This is not the dot register, but the logic is similar.

Comment: @LucHermitte Okay, vim has special redo buffer. This is still seems to me like a strange behaviour that should be changed.

Comment: @user1685095 Not sure this is what you want, but have a look at `:h i_^r^o`. Try to prefix the name of the unnamed register with `<C-o>`: `<C-r><C-o>"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 4 ways to insert the contents of a register.

The first one is:

```
C-r {register name}
```

This inserts the contents of the register, and replaces the control characters inside.
For example, if the register `"a` contains the string `ab^Hc` (`^H` is the caret notation for a backspace), and you type `C-r a`, `ac` will be inserted; that's because the backspace is interpreted as a command and deletes the previous character, which here is `b`.

The contents of the dot register is also replaced with what was actually inserted. Here `ac`. So, there's a double replacement. One for the control characters, and another for the dot register.

---

The second one is:

```
C-r C-r {register name}
```

This time, the contents of the register is inserted literally. With the previous register, hitting `C-r C-r a` would insert `ab^Hc`. The dot register is still replaced with whatever was inserted. So, here you have a single replacement, the one of the dot register.

---

The third one is:

```
C-r C-o {register name}
```

This time, nothing is replaced. Neither the control characters, nor the dot register.

In your case, I think you want to use the third variant: `C-r C-o`, so that the dot register contains the keys typed during the last insertion, and not the contents which was inserted.

[image]

---

The fourth one is:

```
C-r C-p {register name}
```

According to the help, the difference between `C-r C-p` and `C-r C-o` is that the latter doesn't auto-indent, whereas the former fixes the indent.

---

If you think you will use `C-r C-o` more often than `C-r`, to save a keystroke, you could invert the default mappings, by adding in your `vimrc`:

```
ino <C-r>      <C-r><C-o>
ino <C-r><C-o> <C-r>
```

Comment: Do you know how to remap `<C-r>` into `<C-r><C-o>` by any chance?

Comment: @user1685095 Yes I think it should be possible with `ino <C-r> <C-r><C-o>`

Comment: That's what I thought, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @user1685095 It works on my system. Maybe some other mapping is interfering. If you write the previous mapping inside a temporarily file, let's call it `/tmp/vimrc.vim`, and you edit a file by launching Vim from your shell like this: `vim -Nu /tmp/vimrc.vim {some file to edit}`, does the mapping work? It should. And if it does, it means some plugin/mapping is interfering. You will have to disable some parts of your vimrc until you find the one which is responsible for this. Otherwise, I'm sorry but I don't know why it wouldn't work on your system.

Comment: @user1685095 Maybe looking at the output of `:imap <C-r><C-o>`, `:imap <C-r>` and `:imap <C-o>` will help you. And in the definition of your custom mappings, make sure you used the non-recursive version of the mapping command `:inoremap` and not the recursive one `:imap`.

Comment: @user9433423 Remapping works on my home machine, so I guess I'll just dig into what's happening on my office machine, thanks.